# How do you recursively apply file permissions to an existing folder using a Wix installer?

Tags: file, permissions, wix

We have an installer created using Wix 3.5 for our application.  We have users of our application that have existing data in the Common Application Data Folder that we would like to "fix" the permissions on so that our users no longer need to be Administrators on their PCs.

So during the install I added the following section to the Wix Project so that it modifies our folders permissions.  This works great for new users, but any existing files in those folders still retain the old ACL and don't allow non-admin users to read/modify them.

```
  <Directory Id="CommonAppDataFolder">
    <Directory Id="CommonAppOurCompany" Name="OurCompany">
      <Directory Id="MODELLIBPATH" Name="Library">
        <Component Id="LibraryUserPermissions" Guid="12BC499B-4601-449F-9515-4C58A8F29603">
          <CreateFolder>
            <util:PermissionEx GenericRead="yes" GenericWrite="yes" GenericExecute="yes" Delete="yes" DeleteChild="yes" User="Users" Domain="[MachineName]"/>
          </CreateFolder>
        </Component>
      </Directory>
    </Directory>
  </Directory>
```

What can I do to recursively apply the new ACL to each file in the folder and its subfolders, without deleting or modifying the files (other than their security settings)?

Answer (score 0):

Normally an installer creates and sets the permissions so that new folders and files will inherit.  In your situation you'll need to write a custom action to call cacls or similar to recursive the structure and apply the permissions.   There's no built in ability in MSI or WiX to do this to the best of my knowledge.

Comment: I figured that, I was hoping for some undiscovered nugget of wisdom from the VooDoo black bag of magic that is WiX.

Answer (score 0):

```
Folder permission:
<ComponentGroup Id="" Directory="" Source="">
  <Component Id="CompID" Guid="*">
    <CreateFolder>
      <Permission User="Administrators" GenericAll="yes"/>
      <Permission User="Users" GenericAll="no" GenericRead="yes" GenericExecute="yes"/>
      <---- keep adding required user permission --->
    </CreateFolder>
```

File Permission:
Little tricky. I tried using Cacl.exe in Customaction but did not help. First you need to remove existing file to clear existing ACL then create new file:

```
<RemoveFile Id="fileID" Name="FileName" On="both" />
    <File Id ="fileID" KeyPath="yes">
      <Permission User="Administrators" GenericAll="yes"/>
      <Permission User="Users" GenericAll="no" GenericRead="yes" GenericExecute="yes" GenericWrite="no"/>
    </File>
  </Component>
</ComponentGroup>
```